# Changing UITextField text with time lag

Tags: ios

I am trying to make the writing on a UItextFieeld change every 1.5 seconds in this way:

```
-(void)Welcome{

UITextField* WelcomeField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,230,220,80)];
[self.view addSubview:WelcomeField];
WelcomeField.placeholder = @"Welcome";
WelcomeField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:40];
[WelcomeField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

NSTimer* TimeCounterWelcome = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.5 target: self
                                                         selector: @selector(ChangeLanguage:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

- (IBAction)ChangeLanguage:(id)sender{

WelcomeField.placeholder = @"Goodby";


NSTimer* TimeCounterWelcome = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.5 target: self
                                                         selector: @selector(ChangeLanguage2:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

}

- (IBAction)ChangeLanguage2:(id)sender{

WelcomeField.placeholder = @"Friend";

}
```

The problem is that I have 30 words, and I can't repeat the code 30 times. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Put the words in an array and keep track of the current index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
-(void)Welcome{

UITextField* WelcomeField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,230,220,80)];
[self.view addSubview:WelcomeField];
WelcomeField.placeholder = @"Welcome";
WelcomeField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:40];
[WelcomeField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

// global integer 'wordIndex'
wordIndex = 0;

// global NSArray 'allTheWords'
allTheWords = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:word1, word2, word3, etc., nil];

NSTimer* TimeCounterWelcome = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.5 target: self
                                                     selector: @selector(ChangeLanguage:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void)ChangeLanguage:(id)sender{
    NSString * nextWord = [allTheWords objectAtIndex:wordIndex];
    WelcomeField.placeholder = nextWord;
    wordIndex++;

    // assuming to start from beginnning again
    if(wordIndex >= 30) {
        wordIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

One little style-remark: Try beginning method and variable names with a small letter i.s.o. a capital letter. That's better if you would want to follow objective-C coding guidelines..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way to do it.

Define an array which is holding all your 30 words. While looping your array, set placeholder and set delay.

Answer (score 0):

Declare an NSArray which holds all the 30 values and loop through it every 1,5 second until the last item is reached.

```
for (id object in array) {
    // do something with object
}
```